# No internet when obtaining IP address automatically(static works) with HP 1910-8 switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dhcp

I can ping all VLANs from all VLANs in the switch. I can log into the router/gateway from all VLANs. I can even ping 8.8.8.8, for example, from all VLANs. I can only access the Internet from VLAN 1. I get the proper DHCP IP address from the DHCP server when using `ipconfig /all`, such as 192.168.100.150, my computer IP address when on VLAN 10. The PC is connected to the switch. The HP 1910-8 switch port 9 is connected to the LAN side of the router. Port 9 is a member of all VLANs as a hybrid.

- gateway lan ip is 192.168.1.1
- switch ip is 192.168.1.250
- vlan 1(ports 1-4,9-10)
- vlan 10(ports 5-6,9) ip is 192.168.100.1
- vlan 20(ports 7-9) ip is 192.168.200.1

static routing in my asus rt-n66u router:

- 192.168.100.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.1.250
- 192.168.200.0  255.255.255.0  192.168.1.250

This is if I try to obtain IP address automatically.

If when on VLAN 10 I set a static address on my PC to `192.168.100.3` and set the DNS server to `192.168.1.1`, using port 5 of switch for pc connection, port 9 of switch connected to lan interface on router, I have internet service.

I have DHCP relay turned on with `192.168.1.1` as the dhcp server.
If I could get Internet access from VLANs 10, 20 using obtain IP address automatically that would be great. I want to connected APs from guests.

Comment: Either the DHCP relay isn't working, or, more likely, you don't have the switch port on the router configured as a trunk port.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried a spare router as an ap with static ip 192.168.3.1 and was able to go on the web with no problem using an iphone.

Comment: I was using merlin software with the issue I started the thread on. It did not do what I was hoping for. I flashed my router with Shibby Tomato. I assigned the router matching vlans to that of the switch. I setup a trunk between the router and the switch. It all works fine now. I get automatically assigned ip addresses on all devices and can use the internet with no problem. Thanks for all the replies anyhow.